# when use multi-connection with netty, the framedecoder could throw IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: netty, indexoutofboundsexception

when i use multi-connection with netty. the server's framedecoder could throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. I check it. could it is necessary change "ChannelBuffer cumulation" to threadlocal parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a new FrameDecoder ber channel instance as its not marked as @Sharable.

So just use something like this:

```
public void MyChannelPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
        ChannelPipeline cp = ..
        cp.addLast("framer", new MyFrameDecoderSubClass());
        ..
        ..
        return cp;
    }
}
```